# UITabBar in a UIViewController with transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have no clue on how to approach this.

This is my initial view embedded in  HomeViewController:
[image: post creation step one]

I would like on first tab tap to have the post creation view to pop from the bottom
[image: post creation step two]

Then I would like to be able to switch from one tab to another like in a UITabViewController. I have been stuck on this for hours. Does anyone has an idea on how to perform this?

At the moment I add NewPostViewController.view as a subview of HomeViewController :

```
    NewPostViewController *someController = [[NewPostViewController alloc] init];
    someController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 568, 320, 568);

    [self.view addSubview:someController.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     someController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
                 }];
```

and then add buttons to switch between views. Here is an example of one tab button :

```
    UIButton *Tab = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 20)];
    [Tab setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Tab addTarget:self
         action:@selector(done)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:Tab];
```

but I get a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when I tap the button.

Comment: Take 2views and switch between them.(ex: when link is clicked, show view1 and hide view2 and viceversa)

Comment: at the moment I'm adding NewPostViewController.view as a Subview of HomeViewController with a transition, but when adding button with target:self i get a "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Comment: here you have some code